# Converting CSV decimal time value in SQL select statement

Tags: csv, c#

I have a CSV file I'm loading into a dataset. The time field is actually a decimal value since the type is set to General.  How can I convert this time (not Date) to `hh:mm` format in the SQL statement. I'm using C# to create the dataset. I'm guessing I need to cast but can't seem to find a solution.

```
Time        pH
0.000115741 7.4
0.0105208   7.6
0.0209375   7.9
0.0313657   7.7
0.0417824   7.6
```

Comment: a few clarification questions... are you just using odbc to do this? what method are you trying in c#?  something like DateTime.ParseExact? and most importantly - what should your data mean... does 0.0105208 equate to that proportion of a day perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to convert a "decimal day" value into "hh:mm" format, then try this:

```
double dtime = 0.0105208;

TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.FromDays(dtime);
MessageBox.Show(ts.ToString("hh\\:mm"));
```